# Perl / LibXML : keep closing tags when serializing

Tags: perl, libxml2

By default, LibXML will render empty tags as `<tag />`, but I need to have it render them as `<tag></tag>`.

Is there an option I missed in the documentation, or do I have to tweek the output with regexp replacements (or any other solution you might know of) ?

I'm looking for a better way of doing it in the place of:

```
$xml = $dom->serialize(0);
$xml =~ s/<([a-z]+)([^>]*?)\/>/<$1$2><\/$1>/gsi;
```

Comment: In XML, they are equivalent. Why your special need? Something is not playing by the rules.

Comment: I know. I won't enter into explaining why I need this. I just need to, trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LibXML has a [formerly documented feature](http://search.cpan.org/~phish/XML-LibXML-1.54/LibXML.pm#Serialization), that might be considered deprecated as it's not in the documentation for the latest version, but it's still [in the test files](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/PAJAS/XML-LibXML-1.70/t/20extras.t), so it might work.

> All serialization functions understand the flag setTagCompression. if this Flag is set to 1 empty tags are displayed as <foo></foo> rather than <foo/>.

```
my $xml = do {
    local $XML::LibXML::setTagCompression = 1;
    $doc->toString();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $x = XML::LibXML->new();
my $d = $x->load_xml(string => "<xml><foo/></xml>");

print $d->toString;

print qq{<?xml version="1.0"?>\n} . $d->toStringHTML();'
```

yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><foo/></xml>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><foo></foo></xml>
```